# GWT - How do I deploy locale properties files?

Tags: gwt, tomcat, deployment, ant, internationalization

Please help... It is the first time I am deploying an internationalized GWT application.
I have 3 locale properties files within a 'shared' source folder:

- com.blabla.shared

  - StringConstants.java
  - StringConstants.properties
  - StringConstants_fr.properties
  - StringConstants_es.properties

When running in development mode, I have no problem changing locale, using the '&locale=fr' syntax. However, once I build using Ant and deploy on Tomcat, I get a 404 error when trying to do the same.

It seems as though the properties files are not being correctly inserted into the war file. Could anyone please explain where these files should be put and if there is anything else which needs to be done to link them?

Many thanks in advance,
Dawn

Comment: Those property files aren't making it into the war file - GWT compiles a permutation of your app per each declared locale. Does your module `gwt.xml` file have statements like `<extend-property name="locale" values="fr" />` in it?

Comment: Yes, I have the following in the gwt.xml file:  
`<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>  
<extend-property name="locale" values="fr"/>  
<extend-property name="locale" values="es"/>`

Comment: If I decompress my war file, I can see the 3 properties files in the following path: \WEB-INF\classes\com\blabla\shared  Is this correct?

Comment: This is likely because your files are in a shared package. The compiled GWT app doesn't use them at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify

```
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=fr">
```

in your host page (as described [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale#LocaleSpecifying))? At least it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Like Boris said, these localized properties files (e.g. StringConstants_fr.properties) do not actually get deployed to the server themselves. Instead, GWT uses those files (only at GWT compile time) to compile a specific browser/locale permutation in the form 46903BA33EA6F7A2F0D44EC84020A45D.cache.html (MD5+.cache.html). These files contain all your application code, along with the localized strings embedded inside of them. You will have one of these permutation files for every browser/locale you are compiling against.

For example:

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="opera,safari,ie9,ie8,ie6,gecko1_8"/>
<extend-property name="locale" values="en"/>
<extend-property name="locale" values="es"/>
```

Will give you 12 permutations (6 browsers with 2 locales each). You will have 12 such MD5+.cache.html files in your war file. You can perform a quick file search of a localized string literal to see that it is indeed embedded inside one of those files.

Furthermore, the fact that you are seeing your StringConstants_fr.properties file(s) in the WEB-INF/classes directory is an artifact of your Ant build and/or eclipse output directive. Those shouldn't be there. They don't hurt anything but they add unnecessary bulk to your war file. Modify you Ant build to leave those in the source directory.

Hope that helps...